# How many permutations of $x^5 + y^5 + z^5$ are possible given x, y, z are integers such that $1 \le x \le y \le z \le 180$?

Tags: permutations

I initially thought it would be $180^3$ possible permutations, but then quickly realized that something like $x=3, y=2, z=1$ would not be valid due to the constraints. How can I go about trying to figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

count the total number of **valid ordered triplets** of the form $(x, y, z)$. We need to count this:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i}^{n} \sum_{k=j}^{n} 1 = S_1 + S_2 + S_3 + S_4 = S
$$

**case $1$**: All the three values are different.
We can choose $x$ out of $n$, can choose $y$ out of $n-1$ and can choose $z$ out of $n-2$. And all the three values will give $3!$ permutations out of which only one is valid. so,

$$
S_1 = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}
$$

**case $2$**: All the three values are same.

$$
S_2 = n
$$

**case $3$**: $x$ and $y$ are same.

$$
S_3 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$

**case $4$**: $y$ and $z$ are same.

$$
S_4 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$

Hence,

$$
S = {n\choose3} + n^2
$$